# @types/mongoose how to type ObjectIds with a ref

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, definitelytyped

Using Typescript and mongoose, I wanted to be able to work with my custom model types. However, I haven't found an example of a model typing a property with a `Schema.Types.ObjectId` ref to another document. I'm trying to figure out how to do it and haven't been successful so far.

Here's what I would want my model interface to look like:

```
import { Document, Schema, model, Model } from 'mongoose'
import ObjectId = Schema.Types.ObjectId

export interface ITask extends Document {
  description: string
  isActive: boolean
  children: ObjectId[] | ITask[] // <-- any[] works but limits typing
}

export const UserSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  description: String,
  isActive: Boolean,
  children: [{
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'Tasks'
  }]
}, { collection: 'Tasks' })

export const Task: Model<ITask> = model<ITask>('Task', TaskSchema)
```

When I implement this model in my code, Typescript throws a type error no matter how I type the `interface` (except `any`, of course):

```
async createChildTask(ctx: Context, next) {

  const task = new Task(ctx.body)
  task = await task.save()
  const parent = await Task.findById(ctx.params.taskId)
  parent.children.push(task) // <-- "property description does not exist on type"
  ...
}
```

Mongoose handles ObjectId typings in code as either the string of their id or the fully populated object. I want to be able to expect both, but Typescript doesn't seem to like that with this specific instance.

Comment: It's saying `parent.children.push` is not a function. What does the interface `Task` and `ITask` looks like?

Comment: Sorry, the example I pulled was something separate. Gimme a sec to edit the example

Comment: @unional check the edit now...I was able to refactor my code, but I wonder if there is still the possibility of doing the '|' OR typings like this

Comment: Can you check if the type of parent is `ITask`? It seems like it is something else.

Comment: It's an ITask. If I change the interface typing to `ITask[]` and not `ObjectId[] | Itask[]` then this works. That's what is strange though...since Mongo handles both cleanly it'd be nice to do the same when in Typescript

Comment: Have you turn on strictNullCheck?

Comment: It should work. I think something else going on. It would be best if you create a demo repro